# Spread out elements over a fixed width div?

Tags: list, width, fixed, fluid

Is there way to spread out elements, (eg: <li>'s inside a <ul>), within a div?

EG: I have 3 elements, so they all get 30%

EG: I have 5 elements, so they get 20%

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.flatList {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.flatList li {
  width: 33.3%;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flatList">
  <li>left</li>
  <li>middle</li>
  <li>right</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i think he doesn't want to have the 33.3% hardcoded, but the width should dynamically adapt to the number of li elements.

Comment: thats what i want yeah, but not sure how

Comment: You could just use a bit of Javascript. Check the width of the container, and then set the widths of each div.

Answer (score 0):

Set an explicit width of the child elements and float them left or right accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-table;
```

again, my b on answering only 5 years after the question was asked,

but i discovered this (elegant) solution to night and share it for sake of reference, and the general welfare and knowledge.